# cognos report alternate two pages

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN85H.png)Version: cognos report 11.1.7fp2

Hi, I have two pages, page1 and page2 and I want them to alternate. Is that possible in cognos? I have a customer that wants me to print the report in pdf page1 [grant#123 details], then follow it immediately with page2 [grant#123 details] notary signature.

Alternate Pages Like This Idea:
page1 grant#123
$100
page2 grant #123
notary signature
page1 grant#777
$100
page2 grant #777
notary signature

Kindly, aree there any creative thoughts on how to ask cognos to alternate placement of two pages one after another? A render variable? I have tried pageset, page detail but it does not alternate the pages.

Comment: I think you should attach a picture of your idea. The formatting here doesn't make it very clear that what you actually mean.

Comment: Hi JamesZ, I hope you are well. Pic here. It is an invoice summary, a bill, and a notary signature. The customer wants me to print the page 1 bill $ page2 notary signature for Project #1, then Project #2, etc. My problem is that now cognos prints all of the Page1 Bills$ project #1-#50, and all of Page2 Notary signature project #1-#50.
My thought is can I use a render variable to put page1, then page2?
Or Page set, Page set detail?
Page 1 and page 2 use the same detail Main Query 4.

Comment: Create a data item that defines the type of data for billing and notary, etc.
Try page set with grouping on that data item
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.0.0?topic=layers-creating-page-breaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VAI Jason, It has worked. I have an image attached. I have one data item CON_PROJ_NUM and a Page set2. On Monday morning I look forward to sharing this with my customer. Now Page1 Summary prints, then Page2 Draw Request Project#1, is followed immediately by the Page3 Notary signature page Project#1. And so on for eight projects! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfwKM.png)He will be delighted! Thank you!

Structure Is This:
Page set1
Detail Pages
Plant Awards Header and Footer Page 1
Page set2
[]CON_PROJ_NUM data item
Detail Pages
Draw Request Page2
Notary Page3 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfwKM.png)

Comment: glad to hear, can you check my posted answer as accepted?

Comment: VAI Jason, yes posted answer as accepted. We got the invoice completed! Thanks again for your interaction!

Answer (score 1):

Create a data item that defines the type of data for billing and notary, etc. Try page set with grouping on that data item

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/11.0.0?topic=layers-creating-page-breaks